Maintaining Sessions in Laravel POST Route with CSRF Protection Disabled
I need to create a route for POST requests in Laravel that will be accessed by external domains. I have disabled CSRF protection for this route, and it functions correctly. However, when I attempt to submit a form to this route, a new session is created for each request. I require access to the current session within that route. I appreciate any insights on this matter.

If the route is being accessed by external applications you can write an API instead.

API (middleware) doesn't have access to sessions. This route must have access to current authenticated user in the session.

The session is maintained on the client side in this case it will be external application. The API will have no effect on that you'll be maintaining the session on the application that is calling this API. If you want to have some info about the user who has called the API you may consider some kind of token to store information i.e. JWT etc

This route is responsible for handling authentication (Related to SAML protocol) for that external web app, so data about the user is in my app's session not its. The external application is a closed source app and follows standard SAML implementation so I can not change it.
